# Determining whether a foreign key value exists in any of multiple tables that have thousands of records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

When the user clicks a delete button in my UI to delete a product I need to do a fast check to see if it is a foreign key in any of the 4 tables (Table1, Table2, Table3, Table4). If it isn't then I can proceed with the delete. If it is in a single one of them I can't delete it.

Some of these tables have thousands of records and I already learned the hard way that using joins is not the best way because the query takes minutes to complete.

I figured union might be the best way but I am wondering if there is a way I can further enhance it. Or even possibly send back which tables it is involved in so I can give the user a descriptive message on why they can't delete the Product.

Here is what I have so far and it is really fast, but returns thousands of 1's when the product exists all over the place. I suppose I can just do a single or default and if not null then don't let them delete.

```
select 1 
from (
    select ProductId from Table1
    union all
    select ProductId from Table2
    union all
    select ProductId from Table3
    union all
    select ProductId from Table4
) tbl
where ProductId = 1000
```

Comment: also you could move your `ProductId` to your internal queries

Comment: You mentioned a UI, what programming language did you use? Why not have the button execute multiple queries? This would allow you to display a better error message to the user.

Comment: In MSSQL 2008 you have thousands of records and that takes minutes to complete a query on?  I think you need to look into your database structure and how you are joining these tables, MSSQL can support billions of rows in under a minute if you have a decent schema and indexes defined.  Thousands is a tiny data set...something isn't right there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a method with `exists` and `case`:

```
select (case when exists (select 1 from table1 where productId = 1000) then 1
             when exists (select 1 from table2 where productId = 1000) then 1
             when exists (select 1 from table3 where productId = 1000) then 1
             when exists (select 1 from table4 where productId = 1000) then 1
             else 0
        end)
```

Comment: you are like a rocket :)

Comment: @GordonLinoff does this short circuit by any chance? So I would be able to put the most likely tables at the top? I am assuming it does.

Comment: @BlakeRivell . . . Yes, this explicitly short-circuits because it uses `case`.  The conditions are evaluated in order.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to not define any "on delete" clauses when creating the foreign keys. Then just go ahead and try to delete the record. If there is no foreign key in any table referencing that record, the delete will succeed and you go about business as normal. If there is a foreign key in any table referencing that record, the delete will fail. Catch the error and try to give the user a meaningful message: "This customer cannot be deleted as they have at least one order still pending."

This way the system itself will perform the check for you, which will assuredly be more efficient than any check you can perform at the SQL level.

Comment: Thanks for the great response. If I wasn't using an old system without much referencial integrity that is exactly what I would be doing.